# How to scale Flex application when screen resolution is too small?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm developing a Flex application that is designed for screen resolutions of 1280x1024 and more. In the rare case that a projector is used (which usually has a maximum of 1024x768 pixels) I'd like to scale down the application (currently I get lots of scrollbars and clipping).

I've already experimented with the application's properties `scaleX` and `scaleY` as well as `stage.scaleMode`. However, I couldn't quite figure out a way to

- render the application without scaling when the application's width and height are larger than certain values
- use scaling when the width or height are smaller than certain values

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can't you just design your application with relative values, so your application would resize itself!?

Comment: I'm already using relative values as much as possible. However, there are things that need a certain amount of space in order to be useful. E.g. columns in a DataGrid need a minWidth or the content gets truncated/wrapped. 99% of the time the application is used on devices which support the minimum resolution of 1280x1024. I don't want to change the GUI layout for the remaining 1%...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to scale down the application. Actually, the applications children need to scale. Otherwise the `width` and `height` of the application shrinks.

Since I'm using states I had to add an event handler for the `currentStateChanging` event too.

```
private static const MIN_WIDTH:Number = 1250;
private static const MIN_HEIGHT:Number = 800;

protected function application_currentStateChangingHandler():void
{
    callLater(scaleElements);
}

protected function application_resizeHandler():void
{
    scaleElements();
}

protected function scaleElements():void
{
    var newScaleX:Number = 1;
    var newScaleY:Number = 1;

    if (width < MIN_WIDTH)
        newScaleX = width / MIN_WIDTH;

    if (height < MIN_HEIGHT)
        newScaleY = height / MIN_HEIGHT;

    var newScale:Number = Math.min(newScaleX, newScaleY);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        var element:DisplayObject = getElementAt(i) as DisplayObject;

        if (element)
        {
            element.scaleX = newScale;
            element.scaleY = newScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly popup windows and tooltips are not scaled with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tackle this by adding an event listener to the "resize" event on the top level application. Here's an example method handler for the resize event (assumes the handler is in the main Application class, so "this" refers to the top level Application):

```
function onResize(e:Event):void {
  if(this.scaleX > 1){
    //check if we need to readjust to a normal scale of 1
    var effectiveWith:int = this.width*this.scaleX;
    var effectiveHeight:int = this.height*this.scaleY;
    if(effectiveWidth > 1280 || effectiveHeight > 1024){
        this.scaleX = 1;
        this.scaleY = 1;
    }
   }else{
    //the scale is still 1, lets see if we should scale it up
    if(this.width < 1280 || this.height < 1024){
        this.scaleX = (1280-this.width)/1280 + 1;
        this.scaleY = (1024-this.height)/1024 + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be dividing by the scaleX/Y? and why are you using *this* keyword? IMO it only adds another layer of confusion.

Comment: I disagree on using the "this" keyword. Makes it very clear what is a local variable and what is a instance variable on the Application object. I'm not advocating you and anyone else write your production code in this manner but for the purposes of explanation, it think its more clear. If you disagree, feel free to write you own response.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Unfortunately it's not exactly what I had in mind. I need to scale the application *down*, not *up*.

Answer (score 1):

To scale the application as a whole, and not all the elements separately, I removed the loop and added instead:

```
this.scaleX = newScale;
this.scaleY = newScale;
```

Comment: I tried that. However, the application doesn't fill the whole browser window anymore when it is scaled that way. When it's scaled down there appear empty spaces on the right side and at the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution was presented back in 2009 by Alex Harui. See [ScaleMode](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/flex_and_scalemodes.html) to scale application automatically. See example [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/files/aharui/StageScaleModes.swf) how it works.